# Starting from the bottom while scaling objects with blender animation nodes

Tags: animation-nodes

When I enlarge the objects where they are, I want the object to grow from the bottom of the object, not from the origin point, how can I do it?

My Project;

https://youtu.be/oPvh0f-Brw4

example i want to do

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYBva.gif

[image]

Comment: It’s just math. Scale your object up e.g. just in z. Then move it half way up on z (if origin is in center), else calculate the difference between origin and bounding box bottom and work with that. Same for other axis and analogous with scaling down.

Comment: How can I calculate the position information of objects?

Comment: there is a node for position information: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QVJC.png

Comment: maybe first watch some basic beginner tutorials about animation node? like from Chris P. ?